# Creating a remove() method to remove an item from an arraylist (Java)

Tags: java, data-structures, iterator

I have 2 classes Student class and StudentTest class. In my Student class I need to write a method called remove(int ID) to remove a student with a specific ID, from an arraylist. The method is called by the main() method in StudentTest class. the code looks like this:

```
public class Student {
     private final int size = 12;  //max. size
     private int [] ID = new int [size];   //the student's id number
     private String [] name = new String [size];  //the student's name
     private double [] tuition = new double [size];

     int position= 0;  //position to add data

//an add() method goes here, but is not the case of my question so I'm emitting it

 //Here is the remove() to remove a student given their ID number
 public void remove(int ID){
 for(int i=0; i<size ; i++)
    if (ID[i].equals(ID)
 {
   remove(i);
   return true;
  }
  return false;
  }//remove() :this method is so wrong I know, but I've been trying so many different  things and its just driving me nutts!

 //a method goes here to display student info.
  } //end Student class

  //below is my StudentTest class which will be calling the remove() method

  public class StudentTest extends Student {
      //main
      public static void main(String args[]){

        Student stuList = new Student();

         stuList.add(1234, "Jane Jane", 23000);
         stuList.add(4321, "Billy Bill", 15500);
         //2 students are added to the list: in this order; (ID, "Name", Tuition)

         //now this main program calls remove(), to remove a student by ID
         stuList.remove(1234);

        //rest of code entails displaying the new list and so on

        }//main()
       }// StudentTest class
```

Now. My remove method desperately needs help. I've studied the ArrayList class and its methods. but simply writing stuList.remove() doesn't work at all. I also tried the iterator method (I got lost on that one). Please guide me in the right direction ..thanks!

Comment: You don't have any ArrayLists in your code - only arrays. They're very different. In particular, while you *can't* remove an item from an array, you *can* from an ArrayList. It's also unclear why a class which appears to contain a *collection* of students is simply called Student.

Comment: Generally speaking: this code has a really poor design: you'd want to write a `Student` class that holds the information of a **single** student and possibly a `StudentList` class that holds multiple `Student` objects. The way it's structured right now smells of object denial. It's possible that the homework assignment told you to write it that way. If so, do it, but keep in mind that it's **not** a good design.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, I don't like the design either.

Answer (score 5):

I would give up on solving the immediate issue and return to the design and get the OOP right, starting with

1) Student, should that be a collection or does it represent a single student.

Is the an assignment in an introduction programming course?

Comment: Yes it is. and yes Student should be a collection of students :)

Comment: Dont give it a name which implies singular then. That aside, don't implement Classes for functionality which is always included in the framework (ArrayList). If this code you have written yourself or is it handed out in the course (from the other posts it sounds like its handed to you)?

Comment: Yes it was handed. There is really nothing I can do about the names, and the way the program is structured. If I change all that, then I 'll be handing in a different assignment than the one given. The purpose of this assignment is to understand the code behind the functions provided by a class.

Comment: The simplest solution to the question, as I see from these threads. Just null all the arrays at the index where you found the matching ID, the assignment doesn't say anything about maintaining the array, just that the student should be removed.  Btw: Who's teaching this? It's terrible code!

Answer (score 1):

I dont see why you have to have the StudentID, Name and Tuition as arrays, the student class should define a "Student" not multiple students.

**Class 1 - Student**

```
Student
{
   int ID;
   string Name;
   double Tution;
}
```

**Class 2 - StudentManager**

```
StudentManager
{
   Student ListOfStudents;

   AddStudent();
   RemoveStudent();
}
```

EDIT:

The Student Class represents one student, and the features of that student such as Name, and Tuition, the StudentManager is used for interacting with Students objects adding and removing them from Lists etc, as opposed to having 3 arrays containing one piece of the students information and trying to update them all, this is poor design and its good to learn to avoid this kind of thing early on.

When I was learning OOP before I even started coding I used to identify possible objects that could be translated into Classes, discovered what properties they could have and how they would interact with other Objects.

You will see that no-one will post a solution to your problem here as this is homework, but we can try and help you understand how you can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not looking for someone to post a solution.. I specifically said "GUIDE ME IN THE RIGHT DIRECTION", not, "please post an answer". The classes you see in my question were given; meaning i didn't create them. All I have to do is complete the class, by completing the unfinished method (ie: remove()). To change the structure of the arrays, might not be what I need to do, because then I'll be changing the entire program.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 arrays and an int `position` to store the position to add data. If you remove one student you have to:

1) find it's position in the array, say `r` is the position to remove (it can be between 0 and `position-1`)

2) decrease the position (`position = position - 1`) because now your list will be shorter.

3) replace, for all 3 arrays, element with position `r` with the one located at position `r+1`, now you have lost the element at position `r` and you have twice the one that is located at `r+1`.

4)replace `r+1` with `r+2` and so on until you have replaced `position-1` with `position` (the new value of position)

If you have problems implementing this show us some code and ask for help again...

**EDIT:** to respond to your comments:

You have 7 elements numbered 0 to 6, position is 7 as it is where to insert the next value, you want to remove the one numbered 4 (r=4). Here is a simpler solution but it will change the order of the list:

```
position = position - 1; // now position is 6
array[r] = array[position]; // now element at position 4 was replaced with the one at the end of the array, which is still there by the way. Do this for all the 3 arrays...
```

That's it...

Comment: hmmm, heres what i came up with, but it keeps skipping the element i want to remove, and instead removes the one after the next element. For example, lets say I have 7 elements and i want to remove the one at position 4, my code removes the element at position 6 instead. here it goes (thanks btw): 
     public void remove (int id){

Comment: why didn't my whole comment get posted?

Comment: hey pgras,I came up with this code:
public void remove(int id){
for(int i=0; i<position; i++)
if(id==ID[i]){
ID[i]= ID[position];
position -= 1;
ID[position]= ID[i];
position ++;
It keeps removing the element after the next element.

Answer (score -1):

The problem in your code is that your remove() method calls itself recursively infinetly to die with a [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151205/creating-a-remove-method-to-remove-an-item-from-an-arraylist-java)

```
public void remove(int ID){
 boolean found = false;
 int i = 0;
 for(i=0; i<size ; i++)
    if (ID[i].equals(ID)
 {
   found = true;
   break;

 }
 if (found) {
    // remove the item and push all subsequent items to save space.
    while (i < size - 1; i++) {
       ID[i] = ID[i + 1];
    }
 }
 return found;
}
```

Comment: A few notes: you'd need to modify all 3 arrays, not just `ID`. And you need to set the highest element of each array to `null` or you'll duplicate the highest element (if there is one).

Comment: @JoachimSauer the abvoe was just o give an idea, of what he is doing wrong:)